# crear zip de carpeta con archivos dentro

Tags: php, zip

Estoy tratando de comprimir un directorio que contiene varios archivos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He recogido el siguiente código de la documentación de php:

```
    $archive_name = "archive.zip"; // name of zip file
$archive_folder = "folder"; // the folder which you archivate

$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip -> open($archive_name, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE)
{
    $dir = preg_replace('/[\/]{2,}/', '/', $archive_folder."/");
   
    $dirs = array($dir);

    while (count($dirs))
    {
        $dir = current($dirs);

        $zip -> addEmptyDir($dir);
       
        $dh = opendir($dir);

        while($file = readdir($dh))
        {
            if ($file != '.' && $file != '..')
            {
                if (is_file($file))
                    $zip -> addFile($dir.$file, $dir.$file);
                elseif (is_dir($file))
                    $dirs[] = $dir.$file."/";
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);

        array_shift($dirs);

    }
   
    $zip -> close();


    var_dump($zip);

    echo "<br>";

    echo 'Archiving is sucessful!';
}
else
{
    echo 'Error, can\'t create a zip file!';
}
```

Esto me crea un ZIP sin ningún tipo de error pero lo crea vacío. He ido haciendo debug de toda la traza del código y no veo en dónde exactamente deja de guardar esos archivos en el zip creado.

Alguien sabe qué puede estar pasando?

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
function Zip($source, $destination){

    if (!extension_loaded('zip') || !file_exists($source)) {
        die("error: zip extension or error source");
    }
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if (!$zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
        die("error: zip file create");
    }

    if (PHP_OS != "Linux") {
        $source = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($source));
    }

    if (is_dir($source) === true){
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $file);
            // Ignore "." and ".." folders
            if( in_array(substr($file, strrpos($file, '/')+1), array('.', '..')) )
                continue;
            $file = realpath($file);
            if (is_dir($file) === true)
            {
                $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file . '/'));
            }
            else if (is_file($file) === true)
            {
                $zip->addFromString(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file), file_get_contents($file));
            }
        }
    }
    else if (is_file($source) === true)
    {
        $zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
    }
    return $zip->close();
}
Zip("./", './backup'.date('md').'.zip');
```

Comment: La compresión funciona perfectamente Muchísimas gracias!!!

Sin embargo, el único problema que tengo ahora es que comprime todo desde el server root... 
¿Cómo debería indicar el $source para que solo comprima la carpeta folder?

Comment: indicando la ruta ya sea de forma relativa o absoluta! `./folder` o `/var/www/html/folder` recuerda que la en la ruta relativa `./` indica de aqui en adelante haciendo referencia a la carpeta donde esta el archivo...